# Using setInterval() in Typescript React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, timer

I'm trying to convert a React based timer [example](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-lifecycle-methods-to-a-class) to Typescript.

The class looks a little like this:

```
export class Container extends
    Component<IProps, IState> {

    private timerID: NodeJS.Timeout | undefined;  // stops a warning in DidMount

    constructor(props: IRevovlingContainerProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { date: new Date() } as any;
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.timerID = setInterval(
            () => this.tick(),
            1000
        );
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.timerID);  // error here on this.timerID
    }

    // ...
```

In `componentWillUnmount()` `this.timerID` has an error:

> [ts] Argument of type 'Timeout | undefined' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type 'number | undefined'.   Type 'Timeout' is not
>   assignable to type 'number'. [2345]

I've checked `index.d.ts`, which declares `clearInterval()`:

```
declare function clearInterval(intervalId: NodeJS.Timeout): void;
```

So it looks like I am passing a correctly typed argument into clearInterval() and yet it expects a number. What should I be passing in please?

Edit: if I change my timerID declaration then an error appears in `this.timerID` in `componentDidMount()`:

```
private timerID: number | undefined; 
Type 'Timeout' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NodeJS.Timeout` is meant to be used when you're running in the `node` environment. Since you want to use browser APIs, you'll have to use `number` as type for the `timerID`.

Also, the built-in functions should not resolve their types from `node` type definitions, in your case. If you have `@types/node` installed, please uninstall it if it's not required. That may be conflicting with the types that you need to be using.

Comment: That got it thanks! Do people ever use both sets of typing? If so how do they do it?

Comment: I think you might need different `tsconfig`s. I'm not sure though.

Answer (score 4):

React uses JavaScript's vanilla setInterval, which returns a number.
Check [setInterval on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval#Return_value)

> [The returned intervalID is a **numeric**, non-zero value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval#Return_value)

However, the return type you are referring to, NodeJS.Timeout, is the one returned by [Node's setInterval](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setinterval_callback_delay_args). That is specific to Node.js.

> [Class: Timeout:](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_class_timeout)
>
> ["This object is created internally and is returned from setTimeout() and setInterval()"](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_class_timeout)

**Timeout cannot be assigned to a number** means that you are declaring the expected type as Node's Timeout, and what is actually received is a number.

Answer (score -2):

If you defined it as any, it should work.

```
private timerID: any;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. This question is quite old and has an accepted answer already. Consider adding some detail about why this works, or to show why your answer is a good (better?) alternative.